# Google apps and accounts button not working

Tags: google-chrome

I am getting these errors when I click the buttons for Google Apps and Accounts. It works fine on my other browsers. I only have this issue on Chrome. It randomly started happening 2 weeks ago. I tried signing out and back in, but the problem persists.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try clearing cache as described in this article: https://gmail-issues.blogspot.com.au/2017/08/clearing-cache.html. If it doesn't help, try the advice in [this article](https://support.google.com/mail/thread/67062115/unable-to-access-google-chrome-apps?hl=en).

Comment: I found the cause. It was a removed extension called "Open Link in Same Tab" that forces new links to open in the same tab.

Comment: Disabling extensions is found in my second link. Shall I put up an answer?

Comment: Yes. The answer was found from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some advice can be found in the articles:

- [Clearing Cache and Cookies](https://gmail-issues.blogspot.com/2017/08/clearing-cache.html).
- [Unable to access Google Chrome Apps](https://support.google.com/mail/thread/67062115/unable-to-access-google-chrome-apps?hl=en)

The advice that solved the problem for the poster was to
disable all browser extensions and restart the browser
(equivalently, try Incognito mode).

The problem in this case was an extension called "Open Link in Same Tab"
that forces new links to open in the same tab.
Removing it solves the problem.